# Old science fiction short story collection with bulbous yellow ships

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

I've been trying to find this book for like 15-20 years now. It was a collection of sci-fi short stories. I remember the book had these bulbous yellow spaceships on it, or possibly in it.

I don't think it was from a single author, I believe it was like, a collection of stories from various authors. I read it in the early 2000's, but it had to have been at least 20 years old by the time I got it. I found it at a used book store in southern Oregon, USA. I believe it was a hardback.

I can't remember the vast majority of the stories, but I remember one of them was my introduction to body horror and traumatized me when I was little. I remember the book being yellow, but I can't honestly say if that was the whole book or just the spaceships. I recently was shown some works by Chris Foss, and the style of the cover was similar to his, possibly done by him.

I don't have much information, so this might not be possible to recover, but I've been searching for years with no luck and someone directed me here.

Comment: Do you remember any details about that one story?

Comment: You remember one of the stories but you won't tell us anything about it?

Answer (score 4):

**Possibly *The Best of Cordwainer Smith* (1975)**

There isn't much to go on, but this collection of Smith's short stories take place in the same universe at different times. [The cover was mostly yellow](https://app.thestorygraph.com/books/d728feef-69a2-491b-b073-0a5f108a09af). The collection has been reprinted as *The Rediscovery of Man*.

One story, "Golden the Ship Was - Oh! Oh! Oh!" has huge golden spaceships.

Several stories has elements of body horror, particularly the novellette "A Planet Named Shayol", as witnessed by the illustration below.

[image]